# What are the alternatives of the transistor 2sc9013?

Tags: transistors, circuit-design

I will use a **2sc9013** transistor to design a Li-Po battery charging circuit. But, this transistor is not available on my design software. What can I use instead of this transistor?

Comment: What transistors are available and how close are they to the data sheet numbers for the original transistor?

Comment: What kind of software are you talking about? Simulation software? EDA software? Can you be more specific?

Comment: I use online EDA software(EasyEDA)

Comment: There is a transistor called 2DC2412R. It is also a BJT(NPN) transistor. Can I use it? @Andyaka

Comment: The substantially important thing that determines whether a device is suitable is the target design. All you have said about the target design is that it is a Li-Po charger and this means nothing in terms of a circuit. You are using a sim so try a few out then check the data sheets to ensure that maximum limits are not exceeded.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that the [2SC9013](http://pdf.datasheetcatalog.com/datasheets2/83/83137_1.pdf):

[image]

is just the same part as the [Fairchild SS9013](https://www.fairchildsemi.com/datasheets/SS/SS9013.pdf):

[image]

The first datasheet also has the same typo (*potable→portable*)!!!
So you can use the SS9013 not only in your EDA software but also in your design, if it turns out to be more available.

As for the simulation part: LTspice has a built-in model for SS9013. I've seen that EasyEDA can import LTspice files, so you could try to either use LTspice and then import the schematic into your EDA software, or directly simulate your circuit in LTspice.

Anyway, this is the model card LTspice uses for the simulation:

```
.model ss9013 npn 
+  is=3.40675e-14 bf=166 vaf=67 ikf=1.164 ise=12.37f 
+  ne=2 br=15.17 var=40.84 ikr=0.261352 isc=1.905f 
+  nc=1.066 rb=63.2 irb=5.62u rbm=22.1 
+  re=0.02 rc=0.7426 cje=3.53e-11 vje=0.808 mje=0.372 
+  cjc=1.74e-11 vjc=0.614 mjc=0.388 xcjc=0.349 
+  xtb=1.4025 eg=1.0999 xti=3 fc=0.5 
+  Vceo=20 Icrating=0.5 mfg=Fairchild
```

If EasyEDA supports standard SPICE syntax, you could create a new NPN BJT specifying that as its model card.

Comment: Good find dude +1

Comment: @Andyaka Moreover, it's not common that a datasheet is so funny, so I thought it deserved some attention! Now I'm wondering what are these "potable radios"?!? Maybe some new IoT gadget exploiting breakthrough fluid technology?!? ROFL :-D

Comment: Andyaka and LorenzoDonati , thank you both for the these helpful comments. I will take your comments into account while continuing my project. Have a nice day.